# How to display value based on highlighted cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way for a cell in Excel to show a value based on just selecting another cell? Example:

[image]

Column A has a list of car manufacturers. Column B has a list of vehicle models. When the user puts the cursor in cell A4 then cell D2 would display the content of cell B4. If the user clicks cell A3 then cell D2 now displays the content of cell B3. Is there a way to put a formula in cell D2 for this purpose without any macros? It would change value based on selecting a different cell in column A.

Comment: Nope... you need VBA for this (or maybe the Office-JS API, but either way, code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code given below should work. It will be triggered everytime you select a value in Column "Make".

Paste the below code in the VB editor :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim currentRow As Long
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    currentRow = Target.Row
    Range("D2").Value = Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I added the code by right-click on the sheet in the VBA window, click view code, and pasting the code there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Excel Developer Mode (`Alt + F11`)

Doube Click The `Sheet1(Sheet1)` in Left Side

Paste The code And Save

```
Sub test()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set selectedCell = Application.ActiveCell
Range("D2").Value = selectedCell.Row
End Sub
```

D2 is a your highlighted Cell

And Goto Excel Sheet and Open Macro [image]

Select Cell & use `ctrl+q`